# taxonomy in block translated

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks

I have a custom block code this block return a specific taxonomy in drop down list like this

```
function manufacturer_country_options() {
  $options = db_query("SELECT name,tid FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE
    vid = 35 ");
  $rows[''] = t('-- Any --');
  foreach ($options as $row) {
    $rows[$row->tid] = $row->name;
  }
  return $rows;
}
```

but this function does not give me the translation of vocabulary how i can fix it to return the translation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'm going to assume that you have enabled/installed `Taxonomy translation` module.

Second you need to filter `taxonomy_term_data` by the current language.

So your code should look like the following:

Translation mode: **Translate**

```
function manufacturer_country_options() {
  $query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't')
    ->fields('t', array('name', 'tid'))
    ->condition('t.vid', '35');

  if(module_exists('i18n_taxonomy') && i18n_select_mode('taxonomy')) {
    $table_alias = i18n_select_check_table($query, 'taxonomy_term_data', 'tid');
    $query->condition($table_alias . '.language', i18n_select_langcodes());
    $query->addTag('i18n_select');
  }

  $options = $query->execute();

  $rows[''] = t('-- Any --'); 
  foreach ($options as $row) {
    $rows[$row->tid] = $row->name;
  }
  return $rows;
}
```

Translation mode: **Localize**

```
function manufacturer_country_options() {
  $query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't')
    ->fields('t', array('name', 'tid'))
    ->condition('t.vid', '35');
  $options = $query->execute();

  $rows[''] = t('-- Any --');

  foreach ($options as $row) {
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($row->tid);

    if(module_exists('i18n_taxonomy')){
      $term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms($term); 
    }  

    $rows[$term->tid] = $term->name;
  }
  return $rows;
}
```

Comment: this solution work will when Translation mode of Taxonomy is Translate but i need the Localize choice "not work in this " how i can fix it

Comment: @ToseSharef Added Translation mode localize to my answer.

Comment: You are welcome ya m3alem :)

Comment: can you speak  arabic??

Comment: Yes I do ;). However, I think you can't ask these kind of questions here. If you're able to chat, we can chat if you have any Drupal issues, wishes.